# NumericUpDown bloquear Down

Tags: c#, winforms

Como fazer para bloquear ou controlar o estado "Down" do componente NumericUpDown do Windows Forms ?

Ex: Primeiro momento o usuário faz um "cadastro", ele pode Adicionar ou Remover a Quantidade, na segunda possibilidade o usuário pode "editar" adicionar ou remover a quantidade adicionada, contanto que o Down não seja menor que a quantidade salva anteriormente no cadastro.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: já deu uma olhada na [documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.numericupdown.minimum?view=netframework-4.7.2)?

Comment: @AlvaroAlves Sim, mas a principio não encontrei uma solução ou não entendi ao certo a documentação. Por isso a pergunta aqui no StackOverflow.

Comment: Edite sua pergunta e adicione o que você já tentou fazer

Comment: @samuelrvg O que você quer dizer com controlar? Você quer mudar o "step" dele? Por exemplo: diminuir de 5 em 5, ao invés de 1 em 1

Comment: Se entendi bem ele quer que só exista a opção para aumentar - embora isso não tenha feito sentido para mim, pois se o usuário incrementar sem querer, não conseguirá diminuir.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Eu pensei que fosse isso também, mas aí caí na mesma ideia. Não faz sentido ter apenas uma opção.

Comment: @LINQ o que quero é em determinado momento "Cadastro" ele pode alterar o valor normal, tanto o Up quanto o Down, em outro momento por exemplo "Editar" quero que seja apenas o UP, bloqueando assim o Down, faz sentido agora ?

Comment: eu recomendo você criar um textbox e dois botões e fazer isso customizado.. de acordo com sua lógica.. pq não tem nada nativo pra bloquear apenas o down,a não ser que você vá no change event e se o valor for de decremento do valor atual você bloqueia e não deixa ( e.Cancel )

Comment: Você definir o valor minimo para a quantidade atual, não resolve?

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.numericupdown.minimum?view=netframework-4.7.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acho que nesse sua situação o melhor seria o numericupdown puxar os dados salvos e jogar na opção minimum do seu numeric assim o minimo sempre vai ser o que o usuario salvou por ultimo

Answer (score 1):

Penso que é isto que quer.

```
numericUpDown.ReadOnly = true;
```